# A (1.35v, 100mA) LED not lighting after connecting a 1.5v battery

Tags: voltage, led, current

I connected a battery of 1,5V and an LED (Voltage 1,35v, current 100mA), 1,5 is greater than the threshold 1,35v so why didn't the LED light up, I expected a heavy light or that LED smokes but it doesn't happen Any explanation ?

Comment: A very short flash you missed and then it was all over? Don’t run LEDs without current limitation.

Comment: Was it invisible IR?

Comment: @winny But what is the reason, current, voltage ? it should be some tolerance, it is sometime impossible to get the exact voltage and current in the circuit.

Comment: Either the actual (as opposed to the nominal) voltage of the battery wasn't high enough, or you blew up the LED in a smoke-free way because there was no current limitating resistor, or it was emitting outside of visual range, or it was broken to begin with. Can't tell without more information about the LED and the battery, plus some measurements.

Comment: *it is sometime impossible to get the exact voltage and current in the circuit.* - EEs don't try - they use a current limiting resistor (or other mechanism) to ensure that the current does not exceed the maximum by some margin to obtain reliability.

Comment: @ocrdu - A 1.35 v LED must be infrared. So he couldn't see it even if it is working.

Comment: Reason is that with unclamped voltage over Vf will allow as much current as any parasitic resistance of the LED will allow (simplified explanation, but close enough for your case), leading to more current than the LED can survive.

Comment: VTC as unclear because either you can somehow see IR, or you got the forward voltage wrong, or you are using some kind of external device to verify that the LED is lighting up. Something is missing from the question.

Answer (score 2):

You have almost certainly destroyed your LED. An LED will draw effectively all the current that a source can supply as long as its threshold voltage is exceeded.  Most LED have a threshold of about 1.2V (more or less depending on the specific design) and your 1.5V battery exceeded that by 0.3V. That may not sound like much but once crossed there is very little resistance in the LED to limit current. So you have 0.3V connected across what appears to be a "resistor" that is approaching 0 ohms.  At best it's a few milli-ohms.

You will rarely get "magic smoke" out of an LED since they are both very small and quite encapsulated. They "fry" in a very short period of time, microseconds to a millisecond or two since the device itself is very small.

You must always use a current-limiting resistor to keep the maximum current below the LED's specific current limit.

Comment: Ok so you mean the current crossing the LED is to high, I(led) = U/R(led) , R(led) approach 0 means I(led) is too high, is that what you meant ?

Comment: @Mouin: See if http://lednique.com/current-voltage-relationships/iv-curves/ helps.

Comment: @Transistor interesting Article thank you

Answer (score 2):

### Why no smoke?  (but overstressed)

From experience, I expect it is a 5 mm Infrared LED with a 1 Ohm Rs or ESR above Vf=1.35V @ 100mA so from 1.35 to 1.5V  it draws an extra 150mA or 250mA @ 1.5V.
[image: strong text]
Thus if you wanted 100mA you would add 1.5 Ohm in series with the 1.5V battery to drop 150mV externally and 1350mV across the LED.

The junction temperature rise is well thermally insulated in epoxy but for a 5 mm LED it is 230'C/W so your experiment of 250mA*1.5V = 375mW or a junction temperature rise of 86'C which thru a few mm of plastic might not noticed for a minute or less.

Since the soldercup reflector is on the cathode (-) this lead will get hot first. This thermal velocity is about 1mm /s and is the same for a soldering iron at 260'C getting to the wire junction. Which is why you should never solder at the base directly and do so in less than 5 seconds, preferably <=3 seconds per lead so as not to damage the epoxy moisture seal around the leads.
[image]
Since the maximum operating temperature is 85'C you would have to be outside where it's freezing here  in Toronto to stay within spec. (and possibly where you are)

Don't look at the LED with 100 mA or more directly into your eye as this may cause damage, but using the LED's lens, observe your LED chip and compare with a new LED. There ought to be no differences in discoloration, meaning no smoke damage, but it may be degraded somewhat in efficacy.

### experiment 2

You can use another IR LED as a photodiode coupled together lens to lens with tape and a scope probe to measure a pulsed Current Transfer Ratio (for giggles).  Since the coupling is imperfect, it will be << 1.  Report back your results.

[ref](https://www.vishay.com/docs/81011/tsal6400.pdf)

Also depending on the size and state of your 1.5V battery it may have a short circuit ESR of about 1 Ohm +/- xx % so your battery voltage may drop.

Why no light? Your eyes cannot see IR but there will be a faint amount of light bandwidth emitted yet unspecified into the visible red band (<680nm).

This would spread further apart on a log scale but BW is always defined as half power point.
[image]